# React lifecycle method when component is fully rendered

Tags: reactjs, render, react-dom

I need to do some size calculations when a component is fully rendered. The `componentDidMount` method, however fires as soon as the component is rendered, but it's children are not. This code for example:

```
componentDidMount(){
  console.log(findDOMNode(this).childNodes.length);
}
```

outputs `0`

What is the proper way to trigger some code once a component has been fully rendered, together with any descendant components.

Edit: I don't want to use `componentDidUpdate` since that method fires on any update. I just need this to be run once.

Edit2: As @NaisheelVerdhan points out, the docs say that `componentDidMount` ins invoked on children first, but in this case I'm confused as to why my above example returns `0`

Comment: [From the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) : The componentDidMount() method of child components is invoked before that of parent components.

Comment: A hack, but maybe setTimeout?

Comment: Try to use instead this.getDOMNode().childNodes.length, but remember this method is deprecated and findDOMNode was moved to ReactDOM. And as said above componentDidUpdate will be called first in the chlild components.

Comment: There is also a callback in the ReactDOM render method that you could use, but will be fire also in updates since that is normally what you want because maybe your component changed size after that.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you want to perform calculations in the render method itself. Is there some reason you cannot do that?

Comment: The render method is executed before the component is placed in the DOM so I can't measure anything until it's been laid out by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry everyone.
The component I was rendering initially mounted empty and was filled later. @NaisheelVerdhan was entirely correct.